# Creating a specific board for a tic tac toe game

Tags: python

I am having trouble with creating a specific board for a tic tac toe game in Python and I hope that one of you could help me find what is wrong. I want to be able to choose between three different boards, but only the code for one board works for me.

I am trying to create a program of tic tac toe in python where only the computer will perform the moves, ie it will play against itself. My first task was to create an empty board and I managed to do that with the following code: (this one also prints ut the board)

```
import numpy as np 

def create_board(): 
    return(np.array([[0, 0, 0], 
                     [0, 0, 0], 
                     [0, 0, 0]]))
```

But then I wanted the program to be able to perform tic tac toe on three different sized boards (3x3, 5x5 and 7x7) so I redid the code and created a main() function with an input() that asks for the desired size. However this one only prints out the number I selected in my input(), eg 3, and not the board. What am I doing wrong? My redesigned code for that is:

```
import numpy as np 

def create_board(board):     

    if board == 3:
        return np.array([[0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0]])

    if board == 5:
        return np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

    if board == 7:
        return np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

def main():

    board = input("how big playing surface (3/5/7)? ")
```

Comment: See Ignacio's answer below but also note that you're still comparing a string to integers.

Comment: You never actually called `create_board`... And also why not just `np.zeros((board, board))`?

Comment: Thank you @JustinEzequiel , I also edited the input to int(input(....)) and now this also work!

Comment: @Tomerikoo you are correct, I edited the code and used ``np.zeros`` instead and also called ``create_board``, it now works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not invoking `create_board` from the `main`. So add:

```
def main():
    board = input("how big playing surface (3/5/7)? ")
    create_board(board)
```

And you could redifine `create_board` as:

```
def create_board(n):
    return np.zeros((n, n), dtype=int)
```

Assuming you want a square matrix of zeros

Comment: Thank you, this simplified the whole thing! However for this to work I had to add ``return`` to the invoking of  ``create_board`` under main().